# Why won't this code output to a file?

Tags: c++, input

I've debugged my program and the arrays seem to be allocated well. However for some strange and stupid reason, the code doesn't output the arrays into the file.

Please help me spot my bug or such!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void sRecSort(string  *n, int *s, string *e, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++){
            if (s[j] < s[i]){
                swap(s[i],s[j]);
                swap(e[i],e[j]);
                swap(n[i],n[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

void printLowestRecord(char inFileName[]){
    string tempSubString = " ";
    string names[12] = {" "};
    int grades[12] = {0};
    string emails[12] = {""};
    int firstSpace = -1;
    int secondSpace = -1;
    ifstream inputMe(inFileName);
    while (!inputMe.eof()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            getline(inputMe, tempSubString);
            for (int w = 0; w < strlen(tempSubString.c_str()); w++){
                if (tempSubString[w] != ' '){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if (firstSpace == -1){
                        firstSpace = w;
                    }
                    else if (firstSpace != -1 && secondSpace == -1){
                        secondSpace = w;
                        names[i] = tempSubString.substr(0, firstSpace);
                        grades[i] = atoi((tempSubString.substr(firstSpace + 1, secondSpace - (firstSpace + 1))).c_str());
                        emails[i] = tempSubString.substr(secondSpace + 1, tempSubString.length() - (secondSpace + 1));
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            firstSpace = -1;
            secondSpace = -1;
        }
    }
    sRecSort(names, grades, emails, 12);
    inputMe.close();
}

void sortFileRecords(char inFileName[], char outFileName[]){
    ifstream inputFile(inFileName);
    ofstream outputFile(outFileName);
    string tempSubString = " ";
    string names[12] = {" "};
    int grades[12] = {0};
    string emails[12] = {" "};
    int firstSpace = -1;
    int secondSpace = -1;
    while (!inputFile.eof()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
            getline(inputFile, tempSubString);
            for (int w = 0; w < strlen(tempSubString.c_str()); w++){
                if (tempSubString[w] != ' '){
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    if (firstSpace == -1){
                        firstSpace = w;
                    }
                    else if (firstSpace != -1 && secondSpace == -1){
                        secondSpace = w;
                        names[i] = tempSubString.substr(0, firstSpace);
                        grades[i] = atoi((tempSubString.substr(firstSpace + 1, secondSpace - (firstSpace + 1))).c_str());
                        emails[i] = tempSubString.substr(secondSpace + 1, tempSubString.length() - (secondSpace + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            firstSpace = -1;
            secondSpace = -1;
        }
    }
    sRecSort(names, grades, emails, 12);

    for (int q = 0; q < 12; q++){
        outputFile << names[q] << " " << grades[q] << " " << emails[q] << endl;
    }
    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    printLowestRecord("gradebook.txt");
    sortFileRecords("gradebook.txt", "sortedGradebook.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my data:

Sean 80 sean@csi.edu

James 100 james@yahoo.com

Issac 99 issac@mail.csi.edu

Thomas 88 tom@cix.csi.edu

Alice 78 alice@myclass.com

Jone 75 jone@hotmail.com

Zach 89 zach@yahoo.com

Mark 86 mark@gmail.com

Nick 79 nick@bmail.com

Amy 95 amy@hotmail.com

Claire 89 claire@yahoo.com

Eve 97 eve@nytimes.com

Comment: Anthony, please give your input file so it can be tested with that. Both @schnaader and myself have confirmed your code works with our test files.

Comment: Yes, I'd second that. If you can't give away the original test file, please at least give an made-up example that fails.

Comment: The input data you given works fine for me (see my post). Also see the comment on my answer for possible other solutions to your problem.

Comment: @Anthony, that's about the limit of the help I can give since I don't have a Mac - this code runs fine on at least two platforms. As I suggested in comments to @schaader's answer, single-step debugging or liberal use of debugging couts will probably help you track down the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to be correct so far, I think your test data is wrong. If I test with this input file:

```
a 10 c
d 2 f
g 9 i
j 4 l
m 8 o
p 6 r
s 7 u
v 8 x
y 6 a
b 10 d
e 5 g
h 12 j
```

The output file is like this, which is the expected behaviour:

```
d 2 f
j 4 l
e 5 g
y 6 a
p 6 r
s 7 u
m 8 o
v 8 x
g 9 i
b 10 d
a 10 c
h 12 j
```

So either your test data is wrong or there is some additional error handling you have to do (file can't be opened etc.).

By the way, this part of your code

```
                            else if (firstSpace != -1 && secondSpace == -1){
```

can be reduced to

```
                            else {
```

because you have a break statement in there and set secondSpace back to -1 right after it.

EDIT: Your data also works fine - output is this:

```
Jone 75 jone@hotmail.com
Alice 78 alice@myclass.com
Nick 79 nick@bmail.com
Sean 80 sean@csi.edu
Mark 86 mark@gmail.com
Thomas 88 tom@cix.csi.edu
Zach 89 zach@yahoo.com
Claire 89 claire@yahoo.com
Amy 95 amy@hotmail.com
Eve 97 eve@nytimes.com
Issac 99 issac@mail.csi.edu
James 100 james@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Yes, the code is fine, I've checked it with similar results. Ergo the problem you is an environmental one. Does the file exist, does it exist where your program is running, and is it of the right format?

Comment: It exists and it is a text file.

Comment: @Anthony, we need your input file.

Comment: Works fine here, there must be something wrong with your filenames, environment or similar. You could also try to delete the executable and recompile just to make sure you're using the right version.

Comment: Please note that I'm using Xcode on a Mac. Is there any way that I could make it work on the Mac?

Comment: Concur on the output. It's possibly interesting that Jone is the first in the list and, according to OP, the only one that comes out.

Comment: Since this works fine under Cygwin (for me) and (probably) VC++ for @schnaader, I would suggest this is a Mac/Xcode problem - maybe a retag would help.

Comment: In addition, start peppering your code with debug statements to see if you can find the problem (or, even better if available, use a single-stepping debugger).

Comment: I tested with G++ 3.4.5, I agree that this is some Mac (file system/permission/flushing...)/XCode (compiler bug/environmental settings...) problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
printLowestRecord("gradebook.txt");
sortFileRecords("gradebook.txt", "sortedGradebook.txt");
```

Maybe you need to specify the full absolute path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
printLowestRecord("gradebook.txt");
sortFileRecords("gradebook.txt", "sortedGradebook.txt");
```

In those two lines, try writing the **complete** filepath for the output text. I'm thinking that's the problem.

Comment: It's not that, as the file "sortedGradebook.txt" just shows "Jone" and that's it.